# PrintPreviewDialog runs off page

Tags: visual-studio-2012

PrintPreviewDialog runs off page.  I am using VB.net 2012 with PrintDocument and PrintPreviewDialog.  I am getting data from a database.  The data does not go to the next page.  It appears as though it is just running off the bottom.

```
    'Step through each record
    'Load into memory
    sHeader = objDataView(nRec).Item("PmtType").ToString
    'Print the header
    e.Graphics.DrawString(sHeader, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, a, n)
    n = n + 15
    For nRec = 0 To nRecordCount
        'Load into Text box
        'e = refers to print page arguments
        If sHeader = objDataView(nRec).Item("PmtType").ToString Then
            'I'm in the same category, print it
            dDate = objDataView(nRec).Item("DatePd").ToString
            sString = Format(dDate, "MM/dd/yy")
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, b, n)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(objDataView(nRec).Item("PaidTo").ToString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, c, n)
            sPmt = objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
            sPmt = FormatNumber(sPmt, 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sPmt, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, d, n)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(objDataView(nRec).Item("Comments").ToString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, ee, n)
            n = n + iSpace
            nSubtot = nSubtot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
            nGrandTot = nGrandTot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment")

        Else
            'I moved to the next category, skip a line and print a new category
            'Print the sub total, reset to 0, print the next category
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Sub Total:", ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, c, n)
            nSubtot = FormatNumber(nSubtot, 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(nSubtot, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, d, n)
            nSubtot = 0

            n = n + 15
            sHeader = objDataView(nRec).Item("PmtType").ToString
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sHeader, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, a, n)
            n = n + 15
            dDate = objDataView(nRec).Item("DatePd").ToString
            sString = Format(dDate, "MM/dd/yy")
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, b, n)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(objDataView(nRec).Item("PaidTo").ToString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, c, n)
            sPmt = objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
            sPmt = FormatNumber(sPmt, 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sPmt, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, d, n)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(objDataView(nRec).Item("Comments").ToString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, ee, n)
            n = n + iSpace
            nSubtot = nSubtot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
            nGrandTot = nGrandTot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
        End If
        'Test for page break
        If nRec < nRecordCount Then
            e.HasMorePages = True

        Else
            e.HasMorePages = False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: include your tried code?

Comment: 'Step through each record then look for break - too long for all               e.Graphics.DrawString(objDataView(nRec).Item("Comments").ToString, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, ee, n)
                n = n + iSpace
                nSubtot = nSubtot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
                nGrandTot = nGrandTot + objDataView(nRec).Item("Payment").ToString
            End If
            'Test for page break
            If nRec < nRecordCount Then
                e.HasMorePages = True

            Else
                e.HasMorePages = False
            End If
        Next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    'Test for page break
```

That does not test for a page break.  First you need to move the `nRec` variable out of the method and use the BeginPrint event to start it at 0:

```
Private nRec As Integer

Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    nRec = 0
End Sub
```

Your PrintPage event handler increments `nRec` only after checking that the text still fits on the page:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    '' Print header
    ''...
    While nRec < nRecordCount
        '' Does it still fit on the page?
        If n + iSpace > e.PageBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Return
        End If
        '' Print next record
        nRec += 1
        ''...
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to work but it keeps looping through the Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage never ending.

Comment: Not this code, yours might.  Debug it.  Pay attention to the nRec value and make sure that e.HasMorePages is False when it exits the While loop normally.

Comment: nRec resets to 0 when Return initiated causing it to loop.  If I remove Return, it never goes to the next page.

Comment: Well, I told you to make a field and not a local variable.

Comment: I got it!  Thank you very much.  I'm coming from years of VB6 and the transition is difficult.  Thanks again.